# PANDAS Concat is adding a column

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm running an RSS scraper creating various DataFrames with the exact same following headers.

Source Tags Date Title Summary Link Article ID Article Text

I have about 15 unique DFs, which I have combined in a list for concatenation:

```
frames = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]
```

When I run:

```
for frame in frames:
    print(frame.shape)
```

Output is (all have 8 col as expected):
(25, 8)
(25, 8)
(10, 8)
(10, 8)
(10, 8)

After I run:

```
result_df = pd.concat(frames)
```

The result is fine except it inexplicably adds an extra NaN column at the end:

Source Tags Date Title Summary Link Article ID Article Text **Article ID**

Basically adds a second (empty) column 7 at the end... Any ideas about what's happening?

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `print(dfX.head(3))` where X from 1 to 5. Or just provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Best guess? The last `Article ID' is written with an extra space in one of the frames.

Comment: Try `list(result_df.columns)[1]==list(result_df.columns)[2]`. My guess would be the result is `False`, meaning one ore more of your dfs have a column name `Article ID` with leading and/or trailing spaces. Easy solution in that case: create a list with correct col names: e.g. `lst_cols = [...,'Article ID', 'Article Text']`. and loop through your dfs in frames: `for frame in frame: \n frame.columns = lst_cols`

Comment: These three comments all helped me solve it. In one of the 15, I had to change how I collected it. Jupyter always displayed "Article ID" on two rows in the 9th col (I thought was because it was out of room) so I couldn't detect there was an extra space in between Article and ID. Thank you!